# Adding javascript code to sidebar widget area in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, sidebar

I need to show live fuel prices in sidebar widget area. Iam getting JavaScript code from here .  code is

```js
<script src="http://blocks.degalu-kainos.lt/today-avg.js" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

How to add this in sidebar widget area on my WordPress website so that on front-end i will get live fuel prices in sidebar.

Source from where iam getting the code is https://degalu-kainos.lt/webmaster.

Answer (score 1):

Just simple drag Custom HTML Widget into your sidebar widget area, then paste this codes into:

```
    <script>
       dkh=new String();dkh='<div id="degalu-kainos-lt" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="window.location.href=\'https://degalu-kainos.lt/output/ref/\'"><h3>Vidutinؤ—s degalإ³ kainos</h3><table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><th>Dyzelinas</th><td>0.935</td></tr><tr><th>Benzinas E95</th><td>1.050</td></tr><tr><th>Benzinas E98</th><td>1.129</td></tr><tr><th>Dujos</th><td>0.499</td></tr></table></div>';document.write(dkh);document.close();
    </script>
```

**Update**
if your script file is dynamic then use this:

```
<script src="http://blocks.degalu-kainos.lt/today-avg.js" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

Comment: you just create a manual table. These fuel prices should auto update.

Comment: @YasirAltaf sorry fo my missunderstand you. If your js file content is dynamic just ember it like i edited in the ans. But why i don't recommend this in the begin: for some reason, the source file is missing, can't be access or if your WP site using HTTPS (browser will block the file due to security reason) then you have nothing.